# How to get list of all users?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, user

As in title, how can I get a list of all users in Magento ?
Found already some examples but none of those works. All I managed to get was either only one user (myself) or nothing while I was expecting at least 3!
Using this code as a result I'm getting ONE

```
$users = Mage::getModel('admin/user');

$usersCollection = $users->getCollection()->load();

foreach($usersCollection as $user){
    echo 'User: ' . $user->getFirstname() . '<br/>';
    echo 'User: ' . $user->getLastname() . '<br/>';
    echo 'User: ' . $user->getName() . '<br/>';
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the Roles

```
$roles = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->getCollection();
   foreach($roles as $role):
      echo '<br/>Role : '.$role->getId()." | ".$role->getRoleName();
   endforeach;
```

To get the Role users

```
$roles_users = Mage::getResourceModel('admin/roles_user_collection');
  foreach($roles_users as $roleuser):
   $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($roleuser->getUserId());
   echo '<br/>User : '.$user->getUsername()." | ".$user->getFirstname();
  endforeach;
```

Comment: Most Welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Please print the collection and then check data as same code worked for me.

```
$adminUser = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$collection = $adminUser->getCollection()->load(); 
print_r($collection->getData());
```

Comment: Got it, so i must read first all the roles then users within each role right ?